# Building complex pages from a REST API

Tags: php, angularjs, api, rest

I am working on an app with a PHP Rest API backend and an Angular JS front end.  What I am trying to wrap my head around is best practice for rendering pages with data from multiple models.  For instance, if you are displaying a detail page for a 'person' resource, it is easy to get all of the data related with the person.  However, if you also need to have a sidebar that is shows the number of documents that have been uploaded that are related to this person as well as the number of notes that have been created about this person, how would you go about that?  In a more traditional app you could just gather all of the relevant data together in the controller and then inject it into a view to be returned, but wouldn't it be contrary to the RESTful approach to return data describing the person as well as peripheral data such as the document and note count in the same call?  Should these be set up as multiple api calls to get the different data objects from the database?  In considering the latter option, how many separate calls to an api in order to build a single view are considered acceptable?

Comment: Shouldn't tallies like total uploaded, and total notes created be part of the user resource anyway in a regular RESTful layout?

Answer (score 0):

The cold hard truth is that the client needs to have the data to display it, whether the way it gets there is "RESTful" or not.  I'm very fond of the "RESTful" approach 99.9999999% of the time, but also have found a couple times where it doesn't quite fit.  In this situation I think it does fit, though.

What you describe sounds like it could be accomplished by storing the totals of documents, notes, comments, widgets, etc pertaining to that person in the actual model of the person and update them as needed.  Depending on the scale of your project, this may be necessary anyway.  A single request would then gather all this information and it wouldn't feel awkward, and will also save you a lot of work on the client-side.

The alternative is to do some $watching or other event driven requests grabbing the list of each resource type, which...if you're just going for counts most of the time would be less efficient.

Comment: To be a bit more detailed about my setup, the person data is stored in a subjects table, notes in a notes table and documents in a documents table.  This app is currently a fully server side codeigniter app so all of these tables have their own models.  The concern I was having was, is it inappropriate to, by default, serve back data from 2 other indirect models when I am really trying to request the details of a specific subject since the main reason is to support a specific implementation, namely the view for the current app.  Wouldn't this undermine the ability to make the api generalized

Comment: and able to be consumed by other apps without inheriting data overhead which was too closely coupled with an implementation of another app.

Comment: If I'm understanding you correctly, your question is whether it's okay to send back information about notes and documents inside of a request to the subjects resource url?
I've seen this happen in APIs from time to time.  If you request /api/subjects/123 it could return something like this:
`{"id":123,"name":"Bob","documents":[],"notes":[]}` There's no reason you couldn't also implement /api/documents/:id and /api/notes/:id as well to make the api continue to be general.  Certainly having documents and notes inside of a subject won't hurt except if the issue is with data quantity.

Comment: If the issue IS with data quantity, returning a count such as this would suffice (for some reason I am under the impression that you are just displaying counts of each resource on your page).  Sorry if I'm mistaken.
`{"id":123,"name":"Bob","documents":12,"notes":88}`

Answer (score 0):

I struggled with this same question building my first Angular app. The RESTful approach is not a "one size fits all" architectural style...some deviations are often required to achieve the end result. Using Angular allows you to separate these operations out into their own controllers and service providers fairly easily so you achieve separation of concern on that front.

If the end user can create notes and upload documents independent of each other then I would keep them as separate resources. If not, then a single call wouldn't be a bad thing.

Comment: The app is currently a server side codeigniter app and each of the tables (subject, note, document) are served by an individual model (subjects, notes, documents).  Each can be uploaded independently, but some views gather various data together.  

In thinking about keeping them as separate calls, the question arises, how many separate calls to an api are typical or acceptable when rendering a single view on the client side?

Comment: I don't think there is a threshold for typical or acceptable api calls for a single view...it all depends on the app. Take Microsoft's Azure portal as an example; it's a SPA with at least 10 widgets on the page at any given moment that each fetch specific data. You do have to take into account browser restrictions for max concurrent requests. You also have to account for your server infrastructure when getting into higher api call counts. A single api call for 100 users isn't bad but 10 api calls for 100 users and your looking at a 10 fold difference server side.